# Fortran compilation error: Two main PROGRAMs at (1) and (2)

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I'm having trouble compiling this program I wrote. I've spent hours trying to figure out what the problem is but it just says that there are two main programs which isn't any help at all. I would be very grateful for any help. Thanks

```
c   comments
*

    program cylinder

    real diam(10),height(10),volume(10)
    external circ,surface,vol
    integer count,i,j
    parameter (pi = 3.14159)
    j = 0
    count = 1

    do i=1,10
    diam(i) = 0
    end do  

 10 j = j+1
    write(*,*) 'Please enter the diameter and height of
     A  a cylinder'
    read*, diam(j),height(j)

    if (diam(j) .NE. 0 .AND. j .LE. 10) goto 10


 20 write(*,*) 'Cylinder', count, 'Circumfrence =', circ(diam)

    write(*,*) 'Total Surface Area=', 
     B  surface(diam,height)

    Call vol(diam,height,volume)
    write(*,*) 'Volume=', volume(count)

    count = count+1

    if (diam(count) .NE. 0 .AND. count .LE. 10) goto 20

    end

    function circ(d) = d*pi

    function surface(d,h)
    real d,h
    surface = 2*pi*(d/2.)**2 + d*pi*h
    end

    subroutine vol(d,h,volume)
    real d,h,volume(count)
    volume(count) = h*pi*(d/2.)**2
    end
```

Answer (score 2):

For the particular problem of having two main program, you can elminate that by replacing line

```
      function circ(d) = d*pi
```

into

```
      function circ(d)
      real circ
      real d
      circ = d*pi
      end
```

Other obvious problems are sharing pi, count across program/function/subroutines.   when you are in function you cannot see what's in main program.  Easiest solution is pass those along with other parameters.  In the subroutine vol,

```
      volume(count) = h*pi*(d/2.)**2
```

why you have `count` ?

Comment: I only add that the statement function can also be moved into the body of the main program.

Comment: @VladimirF you have to put statement function inside main program (or subroutine, function).  not by itself outside.  there is no choice.  It is a "statement", after all.

Comment: Of course. I meant you can do it instead of defining a full featured external function.